# Moving divs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my problem, I have a div and inside 2 divs, one is centered and the other one is fixed on the left, the problem is when I resize the screen the centered div overlaps the fixed one, what I wanted to do is detect when the centered div overlaps the other div and change its left value with javascript, but is not working, any ideas?

This is my design:

```
<div id="content-wrap">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#content-wrap
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#content
{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 470px;
    width: 760px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#leftbar
{
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 200px;
    height: 470px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 185px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
window.onload = function Centrar() {
    var leftBar = $get("leftbar");

    if (leftBar != null) {
        var content = $get("content");
        var size = leftBar.offsetLeft + leftBar.offsetWidth;
        if (content.offsetLeft < size) {            
            content.style.left = size + 20 + 'px';
            }            
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you don't need to append 'px'.

Comment: If I don't add 'px', the attribute "left" of the div is not modified.

Comment: Fosco, CSS values for left need px, unless the value is 0.

Comment: By the way, your CSS is missing a semicolon: (#content) `width: 760px;`

Comment: Minor note: if you code uses a library like jquery or prototype you should include that info in your tags. Larger Note: I believe this is a CSS issue that doesn't require a Javascript fix. I would explore it from that perspective first. my2c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix would be to apply a [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-width.asp) to your `#content-wrap` container that prevented the overlap from occurring:

```
#content-wrap {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

    /* #leftbar width x 2 + #content width */
    min-width: 1160px;
}
```

However, if you want to use Javascript, you'll need to attach the code to the window load and resize events:

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function() {
    var content = $('#content');
    var leftbar = $('#leftbar');

    // get the right edge of the #leftbar
    var leftbarEdge = leftbar.width() + leftbar.offset().left;

    // check if an overlap has occured and adjust #content left position if yes
    if (leftbarEdge > content.offset().left) {
        content.css({
            left: leftbarEdge - content.offset().left
        });
    }
});
```

The last change you'll need to apply to get this working is to set `#content` to `position: relative` in the CSS so it respects the `left` property you're setting with Javascript:

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    /* remaining css */
}
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/2mAQn/).

Comment: OP does not appear to be using jquery.

Comment: I noticed that in OP's code snippet, but the question is tagged with jQuery, so I figured why not.  Ultimately what they've got should work with the addition of `position: relative` to their `#content` CSS.